# font in image is not being shown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an image with some empty space on it. I have to add dynamic data from sql on to the image and during that process there should be a specific font applied to the dynamic text.
The font is old English . So in my c# class 
I added this lines of code.

```
Font nameFont = new Font("Olde English", 18);
SolidBrush nameBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(35,21,14));

RectangleF commRect = new RectangleF(new Point(0, height/4+16), new SizeF(width, 50));
RectangleF nameRect = new RectangleF(new Point(0, height/4+60), new SizeF(width, 100));
RectangleF gradRect = new RectangleF(new Point(0, height/2-16), new SizeF(width, 50));
RectangleF progRect = new RectangleF(new Point(0, height*4/7-18), new SizeF(width, 100));

StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

g.DrawString(grad_str, nameFont, nameBrush, gradRect, format);
g.DrawString(name_str, nameFont, gradBrush, nameRect, format);
g.DrawString(prog_str, nameFont, progBrush, progRect, format);
g.DrawString(comm_str, nameFont, commBrush, commRect, format);
```

Now I see data on my image but the font is not being applied.
Please help me

Comment: what does this have to do with MVC?

Comment: I grab image from the folder, Add data to image and then save as .jpeg.

Comment: Ok but your stated problem is irrelevant to MVC, you could be using the image anywhere and the issue would be the same. Please don't tag things which don't relate to the actual problem, just because  you use them elsewhere in the application. Thanks.

Comment: Anyway, obvious question...is the font installed on the machine where this code is executing? It doesn't sound like a standard font.